# The following _CastError was thrown building profile(dirty, state: _profileState#96d8f): Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I dont't now why it through error while I pick image also the error happened .I have also checked this error by if else condition but it through same error .Please solve my error.Thanks in andvance
When I click on Button it throw this error

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building profile(dirty, state: _profileState#96d8f):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  profile profile:file:///D:/ecommerce/lib/Add_product/bottom_navigation.dart:31:5
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _profileState.build (package:ecommerce/Auth/profile.dart:54:123)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#5      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19)
#6      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#7      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#8      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#9      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#10     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:881:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
```

This is my code

```
    ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()async{
storage.Reference reference=storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("/images"+id);
storage.UploadTask task=reference.putFile(_image!.absolute);
await Future.value(task);
var geturl;
geturl=await reference.getDownloadURL();
final ref=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Add_product");
ref.doc(id).set({"id":id,"product_name":namecontroller.text.toString(),"product_price":pricecontroller.text.toString(),"phonenumber":nocontroller.text.toString(),"url":geturl.toString()}).
       then((value){
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text("Product added",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  ));
}).catchError((e){
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text("${e.message}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  ));
});
Navigator.pop(context);
     }, child: Text("Add Product",style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue,color: Colors.black),))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on error message it is comming from

```dart
storage.UploadTask task=reference.putFile(_image!.absolute); // this line using `!`
```

You can do a null check first and then move

```dart
ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()async{
 storage.Reference reference=storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("/images"+id);
 if(_image==null){
  log("got null on image");
  return;
}
....
```

Comment: Same error bro..

Comment: Perhaps it is not coming from the current snippet now if you've made changes as I've posted. Also try to debug and check `storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("/images"+id);` result